# How to identify faulty drive on a HP DL160 G6 - P410 Smart Array

Tags: windows, raid, hard-drive, hp, hp-smart-array

I have a HP DL160 G6 Server with 4 HP SAS drive, firmware have been updated to the latest on the HD and the Smart Array...

The issue im having is that one of the disk have a steady amber light turned on while the activity led keeps flashing when there is activity... The amber led stays amber for a couple of ours and then the led turn off. Activity led keeps flashing always.

[Accordingly to HP](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?sp4ts.oid=3884343&spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState=docId%253Demr_na-c00596191-103%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) that behavior is the sign of a malfunctioning disk but the smart array administrator (windows application) says that there is no problem or issues on the array/volume/disk.

This only happens on one of the 4 drives installed on the server.

Should i  just change the drive or is there any other tool or test that can be done to determine the drive status.?

Notes:

All 4 drives are the same model/brand and are HP manufactured feb 2013,
Server is updated - Bios, P410, Drivers, HD drives.
Windows 2012 R2
HD unit model :EF0300FARMU

Comment: You say bios and p410 have updated firmware. How about the disk drives themselves?

Comment: They are also updated. They came with the latest firmware. HPD6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd reseat the disk... If the same behavior continues, then potentially replace it by telling HP that it's a "drive pre-failure".

Please post the output of the HP Array Configuration Utility. If you have the command line interface installed, something like `ctrl all show config detail` would be helpful.

These drives are 15k RPM 300GB SAS disks. They're a little hard to find right now, but don't have a history of oddities (I have plenty in production). The other consideration is that your DL160 G6 server may have a drive backplane issue. If a new or replacement disk exhibits the same behavior, it's probably the backplane. Everything here is within the scope of warranty, though.

Comment: ewwhite, Thank you for your answer. I have found it very useful. by the time i saw your reply i had replaced the drive with a new one. the one that was having issues is now on another testing server (same specs). it has been running for about 15 hours and everything seems to work fine. No amber led lights on. Will post again tomorrow....

Comment: Update: The drive has been working normal since i moved it to other server. The new HD (Same brand/model) is working fine where the old one was having issues...

Answer (score 0):

You may go to the software download page of the RAID card and look for the ADU (Array Diagnosing Utility). Run this utility and it will collect the logs for you. From the logs you may be able to confirm the issue.

It seems an intermediate sensing issue to me. Watch out for your backups.

Regards,
Akhisar

Answer (score -2):

you should scan the faulty hard drive with western digital's data lifeguard diagnostic's tool, Even if it's not a western digital hard drive you should be fine running the san
Here is the website : 
http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?level1=6&lang=en

Comment: -1 no comment? I think this could help OP's hard drive issues

Comment: That would assume the array gives you direct access to smart data. I'm going out on a limb and saying that it just wouldn't work at all, cause the system sees the *array* not the *drives*.

Comment: Yes using this method would require you to delete the array and scan every hard drive.. but you would lose the data so you would need to backup it somewhere first